# Dr Memory and "UNINITIALIZED READ" error when calling FindFirstFile

Tags: c, windows, memory

Here's the following code that I compile on my Windows PC:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    WIN32_FIND_DATA file = {0, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, 0, 0, 0, 0, "", ""};
    HANDLE file_handle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

    file_handle = FindFirstFile("C:\\*", &file);
    if (file_handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        FindClose(file_handle);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run it through Dr. Memory, I get the following error:

```
Error #1: UNINITIALIZED READ: reading 0x0000004f792ff3f4-0x0000004f792ff3f8 4 byte(s) within 0x0000004f792ff3f0-0x0000004f792ff3f8
# 0 system call NtQueryDirectoryFileEx parameter value #6
# 1 KERNELBASE.dll!FindFirstFileExW
# 2 KERNELBASE.dll!FindFirstFileW
# 3 main
```

I spent the whole day trying to figure out where the uninitialized read is, but I can't for the life of me figure it out. I thought this was maybe some sort of false positive ([like this one](https://metricpanda.com/rival-fortress-update-45-dealing-with-__chkstk-__chkstk_ms-when-cross-compiling-for-windows/)) because I was compiling the code with GCC/MinGW, but it also happens with MSVC/Visual Studio.

As far as I understand it, `file` and `file_handle` are initialized, but I guess I'm missing something...

**EDIT:** "Some programmer dude" suggested that my issue might being related to me using narrow-character strings whereas wide-character strings are required. I tried the following code (which compiles fine with MSVC/Visual Studio, but not GCC/MinGW), but I get the same error with Dr. Memory:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    WIN32_FIND_DATA file = {0, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, 0, 0, 0, 0, L"", L""};
    HANDLE file_handle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

    file_handle = FindFirstFile(L"C:\\*", &file);
    if (file_handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        FindClose(file_handle);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The Dr Memory trace shows the use of `FindFirstFileW`, which is the wide-character (Windows Unicode) variant of the function. And yet you use narrow-character strings in your code, which shouldn't work very well (it shouldn't build, much less run). Please make sure that when you create a [mre], that it replicates the error.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The code *does* build and run both with GCC/MinGW and MSVC/Visual Studio on my Windows computer. You might be onto something regarding the narrow-character/wide-character discrepancy; I'll check that out.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Using wide-character strings doesn't eliminate my "UNINITIALIZED READ" error.

Comment: There is no partial initialization in C, so the `file` structure is fully initialized, even if there are members you did not initialize explicitly.  For this reason, the usual idiom for zero-initializing all members of a structure is simply `struct foo = {0};` (and you could try that, but I don't think it will make a difference).  My best guess would be that the issue is in `FindFirstFile` / `FindFirstFileW`, not in or caused by the code presented.